# how to connect heroku hosting with godaddy domain

Tags: heroku, godaddy-api

I want to add godaddy domain to my heroku hosting
but on adding it is asking for adding credit card details .so is there is not method to do it for free [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEUaW.png) or if i add account details how much it will charge

Comment: No you cant  achieve without adding credit card

Comment: how much it will deduct then

Comment: adding credit card  does not lead to  price deduction it just step to prevent spam . If you are using free dyno price will be not deduct and rest pricing you can check at their website.